# How to compute circle loss?

Tags: neural-networks, loss

I have read [the paper about circle loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10857.pdf) for neural networks. I may have missed something, but I didn't find the way to compute the positive similarity and the negative similarity in the case of circle loss.

The paper gives the equations for AM-SoftMax and Triplet loss, that can be computed from a unified loss function:

[image: Loss Function]

For example, in the case of AM-SoftMax, the positive and negative similarities are computed by the following way, `w` being the weights of the last fully connected layer, and `x` being the inputs of this last layer:

[image: positive similarity]

[image: negative similarity]

So my questions are:

1. Should I compute the similarities for circle loss by the same way the paper compute them for AM-SoftMax ?
2. Should I compute the forward pass of the last fully connected layer with a standard product: `output[j] += weight[i][j] * input[i]`, followed by a standard SoftMax function ? Or by another way ?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AISE. In general, each post should contain exactly one question. As a rule of thumb, if you can't put your **specific question** in the title (because maybe you have more than 1), then your post might be too broad. Moreover, note that programming questions are off-topic. However, if you're only trying to understand how the theory is connected to the code, then your questions are fine for our site.

Comment: I have reformulated my question, focalizing on the two problems I have with circle loss computation.